# Which one to use in Room: LiveData or RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, android-room, observer-pattern, android-livedata

I am using Room for my Database management and I was confused in what to use while working with real-time data. For now, to manage real-time data I am using `Flowable` and am I pretty satisfied with it. What I was confused is I can use `LiveData` as well to do the same operation.

To give some context, here is how I am querying data and updating my view.

#### Flowable

```
addDisposable(userDao().getUsersFlowable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(users -> userAdapter.setUsers(users)));
```

#### LiveData

```
userDao().getUsersLiveData()
    .observe(this, users -> {
        userAdapter.setUsers(users)
    })
```

I am not much familiar with `LiveData`, but as far as my research goes it is an observer pattern that is also lifecycle aware, meaning that I will stop notifying if UI is not in active state. That said, as you can see in my `Flowable` code, I am adding it to `CompositeDisposable` and I will dispose in my `onDestroy()` method.
So I don't see point of why I should use `LiveData` when I can manage everything with `RxJava`, which has a lot of operators for convenience.

So when should I use `LiveData` and when `RxJava` while working with Room. Answers reflecting given scenario is much appreciated, but other use cases are also welcomed.

I followed [When to use RxJava in Android and when to use LiveData from Android Architectural Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312937/when-to-use-rxjava-in-android-and-when-to-use-livedata-from-android-architectura), but it's too broad and I couldn't get answer specifically in my case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally working with views it's often good to use LiveData. It automatically manages subscription, works really well with [DataBinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/). it's sort of a data holder that is lifecycle aware as oppose to stream of data (Rx Concept).

In other cases I would suggest using RxJava which has powerful operator chains for transformation and concurrency. Hope it sheds some lights on your understanding.

Comment: I guess that answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be closed but i have a good solution to the problem of using
Rxjava with Room for any transformation you want and then transoform to livedata
to observe in your views.

Check my solution here: 
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833407/how-to-get-livedata-from-room/58124432#58124432)